# I came up with this code for pattern generation which is confusing me. What does the second for loop do in this code??(beginner)

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

```
rows =6
for num in range(rows):
    for i in range(num): 
        print(num,end=' ')
    print(' ')
```

The second for loop is doing something to `num` which I don't understand.

###### Output:

```
1  
2 2  
3 3 3  
4 4 4 4  
5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: The second for loop doesn't change `num` at all. Instead, it runs for _each `num in range(rows)`_. The first time it runs, `num` is 0. Then 1, then 2, and so on, until you run the loop when `num` is 5. Keep in mind the second loop is _inside_ the first one.

Comment: Did you trace it through by hand? The second loop isn't doing anything to `num` -- it is simply using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop is printing the value of `num` for the range of `num`
it basically works like this

```
for i in range(3):
  print(3, end=" ")
```

which will print out

```
3 3 3
```

```
rows =6
for num in range(rows):
    for i in range(num): 
      #the second loop iterates over num and each time prints the value num 
        print(num,end=' ')
    print(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The second, or 'inner', for loop isn't doing anything to `num` besides using it to generate a range of values from `0` to `num-1`. It also prints out the value of `num` at each iteration.

The first, or 'outer', for loop is assigning all the values from `0` to `rows-1` to the variable `num`. The value assigned to `num` by the outer loop at each iteration is used by the inner loop.